# Where to host lots of experiment data

Tags: masters, data, open-science

We are a masters degree student group who have conducted a quite significant study which has pulled a lot of interest from the HCI/MI communities in CS. We have been encouraged to host all our data for the public such that other researchers can use it in their research (them cites!). We have phyiological synchronized data for galvanic skin response, electroencephalography, 17 point face tracking and heart rate information. We also have video data, but those are not included for anonymity reasons.

The data comes from two experiments conducted. The first is a test where participants are exposed to positive/negative and neutral images and included 49 participants. The second is a usability test while having sensors attached, then a cued recall session with sensors (with a new data set) and a cued recall debrief session with SAM values. It had 39 test participants.

The raw data is in the area of 50GB compressed. We have personally used the data for two articles where we first classify emotions, and in the second paper find usability problems / frustrating events from physiological data.

Now, the actual question - where can we host this? We considered github but that seems odd. Does google maybe have a solution? We could host it our selves, but that would mean maintaining a website with it for years to come.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [figshare](https://figshare.com) might be what you are looking for.

About figshare:

> figshare is a repository where users can make  all of their research
>   outputs available in a citable, shareable and discoverable manner

From their FAQ, [What are the file size limits](https://support.figshare.com/support/solutions/articles/6000079074-what-are-the-file-size-limits-)?

> Up to 5gb single file uploads 20gb of **private space**
>
> If these options do not meet your data needs do get in touch with us
>   and we'll see what we can do.

Also, they offer unlimited **public** space, so I think they can cater your needs.

Comment: That was exactly what we were looking for - that site should be more known/used in the scientific community! Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome! Btw, notice my last edit about storage capacity.